Column text is getting into the table
Text of a double column formatted document is getting into the table. Following is my code (refer to the attached image)
\documentclass[a4paper,conference]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{balance}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\begin{document}
\title{TITLE-TITLE}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}
\subsection{Analysis}
%\begin{table}[h!]
\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{xxxx level}
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c c c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Site Name & xxxx Count & xxxxxxx Count & xxxx & xx(xxxx) & xx(xxxx) & xxxx & xx(xxxx)& xx(xxxx) & xxxxxability & xxxxxxxxability\\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 S1 & 259 & 69234 & 28.77 & 73.62 & 2.56 & 13.36 & 64.93 & 4.86 & 68.29 & 31.71\\
 S2 & 95 & 8161 & 41.31 & 109.66 & 2.65 & 14.11 & 72.63 & 5.15 & 74.57 & 25.43\\
 S3 & 57 & 5760 & 102.71 & 196.58 & 1.91 & 5.85 & 89.97 & 15.39 & 94.62 & 5.38\\
 S4 & 163 & 37470 & 37.47 & 89.72 & 2.39 & 4.06 & 31.27 & 7.70 & 90.23 & 9.77\\
 S5 & 125 & 7509 & 79.55 & 271.63 & 3.41 & 36.02 & 217.04 & 6.03 & 68.83 & 31.17\\
 S6 & 127 & 14115 & 89.73 & 207.11 & 2.31 & 6.21 & 74.45 & 11.98 & 93.52 & 6.48\\
 S7 & 46 & 21120 & 14.57 & 33.98 & 2.33 & 0.96 & 15.32 & 15.97 & 93.82 & 6.18\\         
 S8 & 342 & 123467 & 22.86 & 46.82 & 2.05 & 4.29 & 39.18 & 9.12 & 84.19 & 15.81\\
 S9 & 74 & 7309 & 27.62 & 72.48 & 2.62 & 6.34 & 39.73 & 6.26 & 81.32 & 18.68\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \label{table:1}
\end{table}

Following the emergence of Internet of Things (IoT) and edge computing technologies and the development of distributed applications with strict Quality of Service (QoS) requirements, a transition is underway from centralized computing models to distributed computing continuum systems. The latter provide abstractions of the available resources, while they lead to the development of orchestration mechanisms with increased distributed intelligence and autonomy characteristics. These characteristics make the computing continuum suitable for managing serverless computing applications, considering their loose coupling with the resources and the need for reactiveness and efficiency to serve dynamic workloads in the edge and cloud part of the infrastructure. This paper presents an intent-based approach for the orchestration of a function chain over an edge and cloud infrastructure. We propose a Reinforcement Learning (RL) based autoscaling method that incorporates a reward function that aims to provide optimal utilization of resources and timely autoscaling of the functions, taking advantage of methods for workload prediction. Based on a high-level intent, the proposed optimization problem dictates the scheduling of the functions, minimizing the communication overhead and transformation cost while also considering the energy efficiency of the infrastructure. The proposed solution is evaluated with other state-of-the-art techniques for autoscaling and scheduling of serverless functions in a small edge infrastructure. Our solution provides 1.52\% QoS violations with a slight increase in the deployed resources, while also significantly reducing the total cost and power consumption for the deployment of the function chain.

Following the emergence of Internet of Things (IoT) and edge computing technologies and the development of distributed applications with strict Quality of Service (QoS) requirements, a transition is underway from centralized computing models to distributed computing continuum systems. The latter provide abstractions of the available resources, while they lead to the development of orchestration mechanisms with increased distributed intelligence and autonomy characteristics. These characteristics make the computing continuum suitable for managing serverless computing applications, considering their loose coupling with the resources and the need for reactiveness and efficiency to serve dynamic workloads in the edge and cloud part of the infrastructure. This paper presents an intent-based approach for the orchestration of a function chain over an edge and cloud infrastructure. We propose a Reinforcement Learning (RL) based autoscaling method that incorporates a reward function that aims to provide optimal utilization of resources and timely autoscaling of the functions, taking advantage of methods for workload prediction. Based on a high-level intent, the proposed optimization problem dictates the scheduling of the functions, minimizing the communication overhead and transformation cost while also considering the energy efficiency of the infrastructure. The proposed solution is evaluated with other state-of-the-art techniques for autoscaling and scheduling of serverless functions in a small edge infrastructure. Our solution provides 1.52\% QoS violations with a slight increase in the deployed resources, while also significantly reducing the total cost and power consumption for the deployment of the function chain.

\end{document}



It would be better use table*, not table, for a double-column float.
Unfortunately, table* ignores the position options and the table will be placed at the top of the next page (or the middle, if there is no text in the next page), although you can use the nidanfloat package to place it at the bottom of the present page (without any option = using [b]) or the top of the next page (now using [t] to avoid the bottom default).
Besides, (1)  do not load packages more than once, (2) since you load booktabs, better if you use the rules of this package,  and (3) use siunitx to align properly the numbers.
Also, please next time remove irrelevant code from the example. This helps to helpers to help you.

\documentclass[a4paper,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{nidanfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}
\title{TITLE-TITLE}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}
\subsection{Analysis}
%\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{table*}
\caption{xxxx level}
 \begin{tabular}{c
 S[table-format=3.0]
 S[table-format=5.0]
 SSSSSSSS} 
 \toprule
 {Site Name} & {xxxx Count} & {xxxxxxx Count} & {xxxx} & {xx(xxxx)} & {xx(xxxx)} & {xxxx} & {xx(xxxx)} & {xx(xxxx)} & {xxxxxability} & {xxxxxxxxability}\\
 \midrule
  S1 & 259 & 69234 & 28.77 & 73.62 & 2.56 & 13.36 & 64.93 & 4.86 & 68.29 & 31.71\\
 S2 & 95 & 8161 & 41.31 & 109.66 & 2.65 & 14.11 & 72.63 & 5.15 & 74.57 & 25.43\\
 S3 & 57 & 5760 & 102.71 & 196.58 & 1.91 & 5.85 & 89.97 & 15.39 & 94.62 & 5.38\\
 S4 & 163 & 37470 & 37.47 & 89.72 & 2.39 & 4.06 & 31.27 & 7.70 & 90.23 & 9.77\\
 S5 & 125 & 7509 & 79.55 & 271.63 & 3.41 & 36.02 & 217.04 & 6.03 & 68.83 & 31.17\\
 S6 & 127 & 14115 & 89.73 & 207.11 & 2.31 & 6.21 & 74.45 & 11.98 & 93.52 & 6.48\\
 S7 & 46 & 21120 & 14.57 & 33.98 & 2.33 & 0.96 & 15.32 & 15.97 & 93.82 & 6.18\\         
 S8 & 342 & 123467 & 22.86 & 46.82 & 2.05 & 4.29 & 39.18 & 9.12 & 84.19 & 15.81\\
 S9 & 74 & 7309 & 27.62 & 72.48 & 2.62 & 6.34 & 39.73 & 6.26 & 81.32 & 18.68\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table:1}
\end{table*}
Following the ... \lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}

